# SQL / Spark SQL Group by ranges sequentially

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with the columns:

- IP
- timestamp

From these, I've managed to obtain 2 additional columns:

- previousTimestamp (timestamp from the previous row of the same IP)
- timestampDiffInMinutes (difference in minutes between timestamp and previousTimestamp)

Table

[image]
Now I need to add a column called "SessionId" which identifies each IP address and each period of continuous timestamps from 30 min apart. That is, I wanna obtain the following column:

Table with SessionId column
[image]

So basically, everytime the timeDiffInMinutes is higher than 30 or NULL, I want to create a new SessionId.

How can I do this?

Comment: do you not want the session id's to reset for different cs_ip's?

Comment: No, I want them to be unique between all IP's